# Injection of the sessionFactory not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, sessionfactory

I'm new with Spring and I want to inject the sessionFactory and its not working at all. I'm starting a web server Jetty and then I load the context. After i start a GWT web application, I make a call on the server side and I try to get some info but I get a null pointer. There is no error at all so it make it difficult to know where the problem is. I know its suppose to work because I saw it working on a project I worked on some times ago. Any help will be appreciate. (Sorry for my possibly bad english)

Here is the context.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema
    /context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema
    /tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema
    /aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema
    /security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


   <!--  Standard spring initialization -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.test">

   </context:component-scan>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

   <!-- Connection to the database-->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-
    method="close">

   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
   <property name="username" value="root" />
   <property name="password" value="123456789" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Hibernate session factory-->
   <bean id="jpaSessionFactory"   
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
  <property name="namingStrategy" >
    <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Hibernate session factory -->   
   <bean id="txManager"    
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="jpaSessionFactory" />
   </bean>

 </beans>
```

Here is the main :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();

        contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] 
        { new AppContextBuilder().buildWebAppContext()});

        final JettyServer jettyServer = new JettyServer();
        jettyServer.setHandler(contexts);
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ServerRunner(jettyServer);
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);

        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    }
```

Here is the class Test where I want the injection :

```
@Component("test")
public class TEST{

    @Resource(name="jpaSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public  List<Personne> getPersonnes() {

        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = s.createQuery("from Person");

        return query.list();
    }
}
```

Here is the server side from the application (not shown completely)

```
/*** The server side implementation of the RPC service.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    GreetingService {

@Resource
private TEST t;

public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Verify that the input is valid. 
    if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
        // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException 
                        back to
        // the client.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
    }

    t.getPersons();  // NULL pointer here
```

.........................

The MySQL tables are created like it should, so all the scanning seems to work.

Thanks

Bob

Comment: Are you placing the classes in the correct package? (com.test) Did you try <context:annotation-config /> ?

Comment: Hi Miguel, the log4j shows that all the beans are created. I've add <context:annotation-config /> and it doesn't change anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the GreetingServiceImpl class is not created by spring - it is servlet that is initialized by the container directly.  Follow the instructions in this [article](http://mitosome.blogspot.in/2011/01/injecting-spring-beans-into-gwt.html) to fix the issue.  I have copied the relevant code from the article.

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();

    final WebApplicationContext ctx =
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

    if (ctx == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No Spring web application context found");
    }

    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(this,
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
}
```

Comment: For this to work the context should be initialized using the spring ContextLoaderListener  - it is usually defined in web.xml, you will nee d to find out how to do that with embedded jetty server.

Comment: This is something I dont really get. Do you know any references explaining the concept? Thanks.